# Default protocol implementation not viewed by Swift compiler when the return type is Swift internal types

Tags: swift, string, protocols

I have a really strange behaviour while trying to make the String type conforming to a protocol which provides default implementations for most of the methods. I reproduced the error using the following simple code.

```
public struct Length {

    let value: Int

    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

protocol NotWorkingProtocol {

    func implementThisFunction(outerName param: Int, options: AnyObject...) -> Float
}

protocol WorkingProtocol {

    func implementThisFunction2(outerName param: Int, options: AnyObject...) -> Length
}

struct StructImplementingProtocol { }

extension StructImplementingProtocol: NotWorkingProtocol { }

extension String: NotWorkingProtocol { }

extension StructImplementingProtocol: WorkingProtocol { }

extension String: WorkingProtocol { }

extension NotWorkingProtocol {

    public func implementThisFunction(outerName param: Int = 0, options: AnyObject...) -> Float {
        return 0
    }
}

extension WorkingProtocol {

    public func implementThisFunction2(outerName param: Int = 0, options: AnyObject...) -> Length {
        return Length(value: 0)
    }
}
```

[image: error screenshot]

Notice that the StructImplementingProtocol does not suffer from the same error. To remove the error I just need to change the return type of the function which returns a Float to return any other user type. I tested with Int and Float and the same error occurs.

[image]

Any idea someone?

Comment: The code you posted works fine in IBM Sandbox. Can you include the line with the error?

Comment: Will post the error for clarity, but since I only get the error in Tests target I don't think it can be reproduced in IBM Sandbox. But the error is directly on the line: "extension String: NotWorkingProtocol { }"